# Дождаться выполнения Promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Интересует на примере кода допущенные ошибки использования Promise. Почему getFiles выполняется раньше auth и как сделать ожидание ответа авторизации и только потом выполнение getFiles?

```
    var StorageCloud = {};
StorageCloud.API = function(parameters) {
    this.url = parameters['url'] || null;
    this.login = parameters['login'] || null;
    this.password = parameters['password'] || null;
    this.AuthToken = parameters['AuthToken'] || null;

    var ajaxGetAuthToken = async function(url, login, password) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                timeout: 30000,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    Module: 'Core',
                    Method: 'Login',
                    Parameters: '{"Login": "' + login + '", "Password" : "' + password + '"}'
                },
                success: (response) => {
                    resolve(response);
                },
                error: (response) => {
                    reject(response);
                }
            })
        })
    }

    var ajaxGetFiles = async function(url, token) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                },
                data: {
                    Module: 'Files',
                    Method: 'GetFiles',
                    Parameters: '{"Type" : "personal", "Path": "", "Pattern": ""}'
                },
                success: (response) => {
                    resolve(response);
                },
                error: (response) => {
                    reject(response);
                }
            });
        })
    }

    this.getFiles = function(parameters) {
        (async () => {
            return await ajaxGetFiles(this.url, this.AuthToken);
        })();
    }

    this.auth = function(parameters) {
        if (this.AuthToken == null) {
            this.onSuccesAuth = parameters['onSuccesAuth'] || function() {};
            this.onFailedAuth = parameters['onFailedAuth'] || function() {};

            (async () => {
                this.response = await ajaxGetAuthToken(this.url, this.login, this.password);
                if (this.response.hasOwnProperty('ErrorCode')) {
                    this.onFailedAuth();
                } else {
                    this.AuthToken = this.response.Result.AuthToken;
                    this.onSuccesAuth();
                }
            })();
        }
    }
};

var StorageCloud = new StorageCloud.API({
    url: "http://file/index.php?/Api/",
    login: "root",
    password: "root"
});

StorageCloud.auth({
    onSuccesAuth: function() {
        console.log(this.AuthToken);
    },
    onFailedAuth: function() {
        console.log(this.response.ErrorCode);
    }
});

console.log(StorageCloud.getFiles());
```

Comment: зачем промисы создавать в асинхронных функциях?

Comment: @DiD нашел в сети пример, в частности для доступа к внешним переменным, в данном случае AuthToken, для callback, в коде onSuccesAuth. Понимаю сама структура ужасна, хотелось бы понять, как должно быть...

Comment: Если честно, на ваш вопрос нельзя ответить однозначно, вы используете странные паттерны, которые там не нужны искусственно усложняя код.

Comment: Мои ответ немного изменился. У вас есть вопросы по коду?

Comment: У вас auth ничего не возвращает, поэтому дождаться его окончания не получится

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554290/176064

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уберите слова async из описаний функций `ajaxGetAuthToken` и `ajaxGetFiles`, возвращаемые промисы уже асинхронные.

И вот этот код уберите:

```
this.getFiles = function(parameters) {
    (async () => {
        return await ajaxGetFiles(this.url, this.AuthToken);
    })();
}
```

Он лишний, вызывайте сразу `ajaxGetFiles`.

Вообще, ваш код очень странный. Вы хотите соединить сразу четыре подхода: подход с асинхронные функциями, подход с промисами и callback-driven-подход и как соус к этому венегрету добавили ООП-парадигмы.

Ваш класс должен был быть построен приблизительно так:

```
class API {
   static get defaults(){
      return {
         url: '',
         login:'',
         password:''
      }
   }
   constructor(params){
      Object.assign(this, API.defaults, params);
   }
   doAuth(){
      return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Module: 'Core',
                Method: 'Login',
                Parameters: JSON.stringify({
                   Login: this.login, 
                   Password: this.password
                })
            }),
            success: (response) => {
                if(response.responseText == 'OK'){
                   resolve(response);
                }
                else {
                   reject('Wrong Login or Password');
                }
            },
            error: (response) => {
                reject(response);
            }
        });
   }
   getFiles(){
      return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            timeout: 30000,
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Module: 'Files',
                Method: 'GetFiles',
                Parameters: JSON.stringify({
                   Type: "personal", 
                   Path: "", 
                   Pattern: ""
                })
            }),
            success: (response) => {
                resolve(response.responseText);
            },
            error: (response) => {
                reject(response);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Всё.

А пользоваться этим классом можно так:

```
(async () => {
   const api = new API({url: '', login:''});
   const files;
   try { 
      await api.doAuth();
      files = await api.getFiles();
   } catch(e){
      console.error(e);
   } finally {
      console.log(files);
   }
})();
```

И вроде понятно всё и лаконично. А у вас как?

PS. В коде могут быть опечатки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115246/discussion-on-answer-by-did---promise).

Answer (score 4):

jQuery.ajax реализует интерфейс thenable, поэтому всё проще:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fevxdgLq/1/)

```
async function auth() {
    return await $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?auth');
}
/*
Что, с точки зрения вызывающего кода, идентично следующему:
function auth() {
    return $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?auth');
}
*/
async function getFiles() {
    const files = await $.ajax('https://httpbin.org/get?getFiles&a=1&a=2');
  
    return files.args.a;  
}


auth()
    .then(getFiles)
    .then(files => console.log(files))
```

---

Асинхронная функция - это функция, которая возвращает Promise.
Можно работать с ним через await в другой асинхронной функции или напрямую, через then.
Важно одно - не нужно терять этот Promise, верните его в вызывающую функцию. Когда вы пишете что-то вроде:

```
(async () => {
   const a = await ...;
   ...
}())
```

вы порождаете Promise, который нигде не используете. Сохраните его, или верните:

```
return (async () => {
   const a = await ...;
   ...
}())
```

---

<sub>Разумеется, сегодня $.ajax не нужен, в современных браузерах есть [FetchApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)</sub>

Comment: `fetchApi` не все сценарии покрывает пока

Comment: @Grundy, так нельзя. Мне теперь самому искать эти сценарии? Давай пиши подробнее)

Comment: `onprogress` для `upload` :)

Comment: Ну, это надо или нотификации в промисы протаскивать, или на Observables переходить)

Comment: @Grundy, кстати, https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5274139738767360 Ничего не понятно, но вроде уже что-то в Chrome 85 выкатили)

Comment: ага :) они сначала для download похожее добавили, а теперь судя по всему для upload :) непонятно на сколько это где поддерживается сейчас :-)